# How to get BigQuery's API to use Standard SQL for queries?

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

BigQuery is using Legacy SQL instead of Standard SQL despite us sending a JSON payload using the flag "useLegacySQL: False". Standard SQL is getting rejected - but the system will accept Legacy SQL with our JSON below.

As far as we can tell we are following [BigQuery's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs). What do we need to get BigQuery to use Standard SQL with this API call?

Here is our BigQuery JSON payload:

```
{
    'jobReference': {
        'jobId': '####',
        'projectId': 'healthlabs-4'
    },
    'configuration': {
        'query': {
            'destinationTable': {
                'tableId': u 'our_table_name',
                'datasetId': 'our_dataset_id',
                'projectId': 'our_project_id'
            },
            'useLegacySQL': False,
            'priority': 'INTERACTIVE',
            'query': u "SELECT ... FROM our_table WHERE ... GROUP BY ...   ORDER BY ...",
            'allowLargeResults': True
        }
    }
}
```

We can tell the query is rejected from the returning message from BigQuery which accepts our Legacy SQL but rejects our Standard SQL with this error :

```
{'create_table_error': [{u'location': u'query', u'message': u'Encountered " "FROM" "FROM "" at line 1, column 333.\nWas expecting:\n    ")" ...\n    ', u'reason': u'invalidQuery'}], 'bq_table_exists': 'no'}
```

Answer (score 3):

We just noticed that the JSON keys are case sensitive. This is a capitalization issue. SQL should not be capitalized. The correct key is:

'useLegacyS**ql**': False

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, instead of defining `useLegacySQL`, prefix your queries with #standardSQL, as in:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2016`
```

(this works great when going through libraries that don't handle extra API options well)

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#sql-prefix